# A command to copy the access time of files on macOS 11.6 Big Sur

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, copy-paste

Hi I am looking for a command on macOS 11.6 to copy the access time from source file to destination file.

The access time source file must not be updated.

Answer (score 5):

Even simpler!

```
touch -a -r sourcefile destinationfile
```

This only changes access time, while my other example changed both access and modification time on the destination. See `man touch` for details.

> *Note*: On macOS 11.6, 10.14 (and probably earlier), if the touched file is non-zero length and in a folder indexed by Spotlight, Spotlight will update the access time to the current time soon after the access time is set. Preferences/Spotlight/Privacy can be used to exclude folders from Spotlight indexing.

Answer (score 1):

This script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) source destination"
    exit 1
fi

FMT="%Y%m%d%H%M.%S"
atime=$(stat -f %Sa -t "$FMT" "$1")
if [ -n "$atime" ]; then
    touch -t "$atime" "$2"
fi
```

It copies the access time using stat, and writes using touch.

Comment: You can avoid overwriting the modification time with the access time by using the `-a` option, as in `touch -a -t "$atime" "$2"`. Also, the note given in MichaelR's [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427331/a-command-to-copy-the-access-time-of-files-on-macos-11-6-big-sur/427339#427339) should apply to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
cp -p source destination
```

will do the job.

From man pages  :

> -p   Cause cp to preserve the following attributes of each source file
> in the copy: modification time, access time, file flags, file mode,
> user ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.  Access Control
> Lists (ACLs) and Extended Attributes (EAs), including resource forks, will also be preserved.

Comment: This copies the contents of the file (and everything else it can), not just the access time.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of too - the question was unclear at first reading, and a rather unusual request! Upvoted for being a useful tip anyway.